# Using wild-cards in Lucene connector of GraphDB

Tags: lucene, wildcard, graphdb

I'm using GraphDB's [Lucene connectors](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/lucene-graphdb-connector.html). I build the index `my_index` for entities codes in my triple store and I'd like to use such an index for substring matching.

**Example.**

Entities codes:

```
FooBar
FooBaz
BazFoo
```

Lucene Connector:

```
PREFIX :<http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX inst:<http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>
INSERT DATA {
    inst:my_index :createConnector '''
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "code",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://foo#identifier"
      ],
      "indexed": true,
      "stored": true,
      "analyzed": true,
      "multivalued": true,
      "facet": true
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    http://foo#MyType"
  ],
  "stripMarkup": false
}
''' .
}
```

`SPARQL` query harnessing Lucene connector:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>

SELECT ?entity {
  ?search a inst:my_index ;
      :query "code:Foo*" ;
      :entities ?entity .
}
```

I'd like to get all entities with a code starting with `Foo` (i.e., `FooBar`, `FooBaz`), but I get an empty resultset instead.

How can I get them?

**Edit:**

After having tried out the example in the Vassil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51024119/4820341), I found out that the problem could be related to **case sensitivity**.

Behavior:

- `:query "label:Foo*"` returns nothing
- `:query "label:foo*"` returns `FooBar` and `FooBaz`

Comment: I suggest `swrlb:startsWith("Foo")`

Comment: Does it use some kind of indexing?

Comment: Nop, but fatest than regex for string matching.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to use Lucene for those kinds of text search.

Answer (score 2):

The prefix search should work by default out of the box. I suspect that there is another problem with your query. What will happen if you search for all possible values with `:query "*:*"`?

Here is the test case to check and repeat it with your dataset.

**Generate sample dummy data**

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
INSERT DATA
{
    <urn:1> a <urn:type>;
        rdfs:label "FooBar".
    <urn:2> a <urn:type>;
        rdfs:label "FooBaz".
    <urn:3> a <urn:type>;
        rdfs:label "BazFoo".
}
```

You would need also to define `rdf:type` statement for each RDF resource.

**Create Lucene Connector**

```
PREFIX :<http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX inst:<http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>
INSERT DATA {
    inst:my_index :createConnector '''
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "label",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
      ],
      "indexed": true,
      "stored": true,
      "analyzed": true,
      "multivalued": true,
      "facet": true
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    "urn:type"
  ],
  "stripMarkup": false
}
''' .
}
```

The connector will index all `rdfs:label` values for all `urn:type` classes.

**Test the prefix search**

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene#>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/lucene/instance#>

SELECT ?entity {
  ?search a inst:my_index ;
      :query "label:Foo*" ;
      :entities ?entity .
}
```

The database returns `urn:1` and `urn:2`

Comment: If I search for all possible values (`:query "*:*"`) I get them all.

Comment: I've just updated the question with my connector. It seems ok. I do not understand where the problem is : /

Comment: Follow Up. Just tried your example but I observed the same problem: `:query "label:*"` returns all the 3 items, `:query "label:Foo*"` returns nothing.

Comment: Follow Up#2. Strangely enough, `:query "label:foo*"` returns `urn:1` and `urn:2` (labelled as `FooBar` and `FooBaz` respectively). Something strage is going on...